# Is it possible to use std::byte as the underlying type for an enum class?

Tags: c++, c++17

Since `std::byte` is by definition not an integral type, the following fragment is ill-formed:

```
enum class foo : std::byte
{
    bar = 1,
    baz = 2
};
```

Is there a way in C++17 to do something equivalent to this?

Edit: I'm not trying to solve any particular problem. Obviously `enum class whatever : unsigned char` would do it. However, I was expecting `std::byte` to be a little more flexible and wanted to know whether this is possible at all.

Comment: Use `unsigned char` as the underlying type?

Comment: Why would you want to use `std::byte` as an enum underlying type? (or use it at all, for what that matters)

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Barry: I'm not trying to solve any particular problem. Just thought that `std::byte` would have been nice to have as the underlying type in the `enum class`es for a binary protocol code I was modernizing today.

Comment: @Barry: At first impression, `std::byte` seems to be a way to manipulate memory at the bit level without the inconsistency of it being interpretable as text or numeric data for the sake of backwards-compatibility. However, to do so the standard had to define it as `enum class byte : unsigned char`. As a result, you can't have a "enum class of bytes", so to speak. Hence, either you manipulate `std::byte`s using hard-coded magic values, `static_cast<>` your way around, or not use `std::byte` at all. To me, this seems to defeat its usability in working with binary protocols and formats.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`std::byte` is [defined by the standard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) to be an `enum class`. Therefore, it has an underlying type (of `unsigned char`). So you can create an enum with the same underlying type:

```
enum class foo : std::underlying_type_t<std::byte>
{...};
```

Comment: That seems like a very un-useful definition of "byte". Sometimes the decisions of the C++ standards committee mystify me.

Comment: @MarkRansom: It matches the use that they want it to have. 1) it's not an integer type, so integer literals don't convert to it and it is certainly not a character. 2) it has well-defined *explicit* conversions from integers, so you can still use integers. 3) it is a distinct type from all other types, so you can overload operators for various byte-specific uses.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Maybe it was modeled around too constrained use cases? I mean, your proposed solution is the same as `enum class foo : unsigned char` (albeit with an extra bit of intention given to the reader). Obviously that would do it, but still seems to me to be a hack around a flaw in `std::byte`s design.

Comment: @3442: But `byte` is not supposed to be an integer; that's kinda the point of the type. So a better question is why you want to create an enumeration that uses `byte` as its underlying type.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Conceptually, an enumeration might be made up of elements other than integers, kind of like a set, as long as you can define some kind of strict weak ordering among its elements. However, the standard's definition of `enum class` mandates that all underlying types must be integral. I was intending to use `byte` in the spirit of the former definition.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` instead.