# upgrading byte enums to c++17

Tags: c++, enums, c++17, std-byte

I have a codebase with byte defined like so:

```
typedef unsigned char byte;
```

And this enum:

```cpp
enum SymbolTypes
{
    VARIABLE_SYMBOL_TYPE = 0,
    IDENTIFIER_SYMBOL_TYPE = 1,
    STR_CONSTANT_SYMBOL_TYPE = 2,
    INT_CONSTANT_SYMBOL_TYPE = 3,
    FLOAT_CONSTANT_SYMBOL_TYPE = 4,
    UNDEFINED_SYMBOL_TYPE = 5
};
```

At some point there is a comparison between a `byte` value and a member of this enum:

```cpp
byte symbol_type = 0;
...
bool is_variable() { return (symbol_type == VARIABLE_SYMBOL_TYPE); }
```

When setting the compiler to use C++17, I get these errors:

```
error: reference to ‘byte’ is ambiguous
```

So I figured that maybe I'm supposed to be using `std::byte` now. After changing `symbol_type` to a `std::byte`, there is a new compiler error telling me that there's no operator `==` that matches the operands of `std::byte` and `SymbolTypes`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783119/is-it-possible-to-use-stdbyte-as-the-underlying-type-for-an-enum-class) SO answer says we can use an underlying type of `std::byte` like so:

```cpp
enum SymbolTypes : std::underlying_type_t<std::byte>
{
    VARIABLE_SYMBOL_TYPE = 0,
    IDENTIFIER_SYMBOL_TYPE = 1,
    STR_CONSTANT_SYMBOL_TYPE = 2,
    INT_CONSTANT_SYMBOL_TYPE = 3,
    FLOAT_CONSTANT_SYMBOL_TYPE = 4,
    UNDEFINED_SYMBOL_TYPE = 5
};
```

However, the compiler still complains that there's no `==` operator with operands of type `std::byte` and `SymbolTypes`. How do I get this simple comparison line to compile correctly? Or should I be doing something else to avoid the usage of `std::byte`?

Comment: Guess you have a `using namespace std` somewhere, despite the common advice not to. Namespaces exists exactly so `::byte` is distinct from `std::byte`

Comment: Yes the (inherited, quite old) codebase is littered with these .

Comment: @NateGlenn Sounds like a prime opportunity to delete (some of) them.

Comment: Will do. Still curious, though, is it impossible to compare std::byte enum members in this way?

Comment: @NateGlenn `std::byte` is an `enum class` and `enum class`es were introduced so we could have enumerations that are not implicitly convertible to their underlying type.

Comment: @NathanOliver That clears it up. It's definitely not usable for my use case. Thanks!

Comment: @NateGlenn `enum class` simply prevents *implicit* conversions, but you can use an *explicit* conversion when performing your comparisons.